# Locking down all apps except the phone/call app on the iPhone 4 running iOS6?

Tags: applications, iphone, security, ios

Is there a way to lock out all apps except just the phone app in order to make calls?

I understand "Guided Access" isolates you to a particular app and not let you move out. 
This works fine but is annoying as you cannot lock the phone (in other words "The hardware buttons are always off") when its on. Is there a way for me to enable just the lock button?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I psoted the question a little too ealry. Anywyas here is exactly what I was looking for:

Settings>>General>>Accessibility>>Guided Acess>>

Turn the guided access on and also enable the sleep/wake button.

You could put in a password now or later (when you turn it on using the triple trigger and start guided access it will prompt you for a passcode)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on **[Restrictions](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4213)** in iOS Settings (in the General section), which allows you to disable all non-standard apps, as well as some of the built-in ones (such as Safari, Camera, FaceTime, iTunes and Siri). Unfortunately, I believe a few built-in apps remain, such as Messages, Calendar and Maps, I'm not aware of a way to disable them completely.

A word of caution if you're testing this out—disabling apps, then re-enabling them will destroy your home screen organization.

Comment: Thanks for the post, but I think I found a way to get exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called "App Lock" that will help you in hiding your apps and other files like private photos.

Comment: I fixed the all-CAPS-post for you (most people consider it to be shouting), could you please a bit more details about the app and provide a link?